# WebView Activity Indicator won't stop spinning - iPhone Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, uiactivityindicatorview

I would like it to stop spinning once the website finishes loading...

The code I have it:

in my .h

```
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
```

in my .m

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
self.view = webView;
}
```

I then hooked it up to files owner in the nib. It spins, but doesn't stop! Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the web view ever actually finish loading? Set a breakpoint and see if you ever even hit that method.

And, for completeness...you do have the delegate of the webview set to your view controller, correct (I assume you do, as it starts animating, but you never know)?

There are two ways you can set the delegate of the webview. If you have it in your nib, control click on the webview and drag from the delegate property to File's Owner. Or, in viewDidLoad, just say _webView.delegate = self;

***UPDATE:*** After our conversation, and in regards to the comments below, I just want to add this for completeness, and for anyone else who sees this in the future with the same issue. The reason your webView was getting huge after it finished loading was because you were assigning it to the view property of your view controller when you said self.view = webview. No need for that. Take that out, and you'll be fine.

Comment: That may be it...It may just start spinning (and continue) because I have the behavior set to animating in the nib settings...will you clarify how I can check if I have the delegate of the webview set to my view controller?

Comment: I just connected web view delegate to the actual spinner and its still not working...not sure if this was what you were talking about?

Comment: Do you ever hit that method? Set a breakpoint. Implemented webView:didFailLoadWithError: as well and see if there is an error

Comment: I set a breakpoint at 'webViewDidStartLoad' and 'webViewDidFinishLoad'...neither stopped. Any idea why? Let me know if I can give you any more info to help...Thanks!

Comment: Then you didn't connect the webView delegate properly. Are these methods in the view controller associated with the nib the webview is in? For safety's sake, in viewDidLoad say webViewIVar.delegate = self;, filling in webViewIVar for whatever IBOutlet you named your webView

Comment: I did that... Now it hits both breakpoints, but as soon as the web view now loads it gets bigger and takes over the whole screen. previously it was in a smaller frame. It gives the warning: Assigning to 'id<UIWebViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ThirdViewController *const __strong'. Sorry I am so bad at this...I'm a high school student basically just starting with objective C. any other ideas?

Comment: We should take this to chat to keep this comment list from getting too long. You should declare in your ViewController (whichever one is the file's owner of the webview) that is conforms to the UIWebViewDelegate protocol. You do that in brackets after @interface

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10007/discussion-between-fitz-and-jmstone)

Answer (score 0):

should work the way you implemented it.

Add following code

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [loadIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Maybe your UIWebView doesn't finish loading properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct toggle settings on the actual UIActivityIndicatorView object in Interface Builder and make sure it's linked correctly. I believe you want "hides when stopped".

Also make sure you have the WebView Delegate implemented.

Comment: He should make sure the Webview is hooking into IB as well so the delegate know when the webview is done loading.